# Should this question be deleted?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85166/23970) was asked, answered, then largely edited. Now the original question wasn't great and got closed for reasons-I-can't-remember. But it was [answered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/85167/23970) in good faith, and that good-faith answer now no longer addresses the (new) question.

If the answerer were to delete their answer my understanding is that it'll count "against" them in some user analyses. Since it seems a bit misdirected for the answerer to "take a hit" because of the question edit, should we be looking at deleting the question instead, and asking OP to re-ask their (hopefully clearer) question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, just delete the answer.

It sucks when a question changes a lot, which is why we try to put unclear questions on hold quickly.

But there is no value in reasking.  It's why we have editing.  And in the end, you can't control what others do, just what you do.  Just delete the answer.

Comment: Can you confirm or deny nitsua60's concern about any negative consequences of a user deleting their own answer? I always assumed that the only effect would be a reversal of any reputation gains or losses associated with the post (and in this case, the answer has a score of 0, so that's clearly not an issue here).

Comment: @mxy if it helps you find an answer to DanHenderson's question, I'm thinking of something I read at some point on meta.SE about deleted posts counting "against" a user in some fashion, and how it was strongly encouraged to edit existing, deleted posts into shape rather than just leaving them on one's ledger as-is. But I searched around last night and couldn't find anything... sorry!

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: @nitsua60 Deleting posts factors into the automatic [answer-ban system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) in some undisclosed way (but a secondary way, I think), but you have to have a *really* bad track record for answering (*lots* of way-downvoted answers) before worrying about the effect of one post being deleted.

Comment: Yes, thanks for finding it--that's what was in the back of my mind, and you're right that a single deleted answer isn't going to appreciably impact that factor.

Answer (score -2):

I think that would be best. The question could definitely be altered to make for a more useful answer, but if there is penalty attached to deleting an answer should it no longer be appropriate, that penalty isn't being applied as intended in this case. That said I'm obviously not in an impartial position here, nor do I have enough experience with the site to make the most informed call.

Answer (score -4):

Although there's already an accepted answer for this meta post. I feel like deleting the answer takes away from the historical record of the knowledge base that RPG.SE develops overtime. At some point in time, the answer was provided to a question that was asked.

The question has since been lost due to editing, but the answer could still be of importance to future users with similar question or concern. The original question you answered will likely not get reasked by the original asker, so if you delete your answer, future users will not find it and benefit from it.

I propose that, if possible, you should edit a summary of the original question into the beginning of your answer and make a note in your answer that the question has since changed drastically since the time of the answer.

---

This answer does not seek to remedy any issues with user analyses as a result of decisions made in this regard.

Comment: Questions don't belong in answers. If the answer to a different question needs preserving, the way to do that is for someone, possibly the answer-author, to post the question themself and self-answer it.